# running background service continuously and ui interaction in android

Tags: android

I have a situation to run my application as service in background continuously , and ui interation with the service is required for the configuration n operation of service. please suggest me the best solution in android for my problem .

Answer (score 0):

Seem that you need [Broadcastreceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all a service is a component which runs in the background and it does not provide any user interface,so you need not make it run in a background.

If you have heavy operations when a user interacts with the UI , place the heavy operation in a separate thread and push the data to the UI.

here is an example for creating a service:

http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

here is an example for threading

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

hope this helps!

Comment: hi dood thanks for ur suggestion. i learned that running background services continuously is not a good thing to do. and i need my application to to run continuously as it is kind of server which may get request from client any time. give me good example of suggestion to run my app continuously and should never get killed.